# Executable war incorrect package structure

Tags: maven, spring-boot, weblogic, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to deploy an [executable war file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-war-file-structure) to a web server (weblogic in this instance). I also want to add some external dependencies (jar files) in a different folder. The ultimate goal is to deploy a skinny WAR in an EAR

From the documentation my spring-boot-maven-plugin looks like this:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <layout>ZIP</layout>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Without `<layout>ZIP</layout>` I get the correct package structure and can run the war using `java -jar Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` and I can deploy to Weblogic

The problem is I cannot add external dependencies using this method. For that I was hoping to use the [PropertiesLauncher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-property-launcher-features), but when I add the `<layout>ZIP</layout>` config my archive structure changes.

This is without ZIP

```
Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
├───META-INF
│   └───maven
│       └───com.poc
│           └───Web
├───org
│   └───springframework
│       └───boot
│           └───loader
│               ├───archive
│               ├───data
│               ├───jar
│               └───util
└───WEB-INF
    ├───classes
    │   └───com
    │       └───poc
    │           └───config
    │           └───controller
    ├───lib
    └───lib-provided
```

Manifest file looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: Web
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Start-Class: com.poc.WebApplication
Spring-Boot-Classes: WEB-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: WEB-INF/lib/
Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.2.0.RELEASE
Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.4.0
Implementation-Vendor: None
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher
```

This is with the ZIP option:

```
Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
├───BOOT-INF
│   ├───classes
│   │   └───WEB-INF
│   │       ├───classes
│   │       │   └───com
│   │       │       └───poc
│   │       │           └───config
│   │       │           └───controller
│   │       └───lib
│   └───lib
├───META-INF
│   └───maven
│       └───com.poc
│           └───Web
└───org
    └───springframework
        └───boot
            └───loader
                ├───archive
                ├───data
                ├───jar
                └───util
```

The manifest file now looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: Web
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Start-Class: WEB-INF.classes.com.poc.WebApplication
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.2.0.RELEASE
Created-By: Maven Archiver 3.4.0
Implementation-Vendor: None
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

When I try to run the WAR now I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WEB-INF/classes/com/poc/WebApplication (wrong name: com/poc/WebApplication)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:92)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:597)
```

I've tried the following without any luck:

```
java -Dloader.path=WEB-INF/lib-provided,WEB-INF/lib,WEB-INF/classes -jar Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
java -Dloader.path=BOOT-INF/lib,BOOT-INF/classes,WEB-INF/lib-provided,WEB-INF/lib,WEB-INF/classes -jar Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
java -Dloader.path=BOOT-INF/lib/**,BOOT-INF/classes/**,WEB-INF/lib-provided,WEB-INF/lib,WEB-INF/classes -jar Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

I also tried to specify the main class but still get NoClassDefFoundError:

```
java -Dloader.path=BOOT-INF/lib/**,BOOT-INF/classes/**,WEB-INF/lib-provided,WEB-INF/lib,WEB-INF/classes -Dloader.main=BOOT-INF.classes.WEB-INF.classes.com.poc.WebApplication -jar Web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

I also tried to specify the classpath using `java -cp` but still no luck...

Is this a bug in the plugin?
My directory structure looks different to the one specified in the docs for [executable war file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-war-file-structure)

Is it even possible to use the PropertiesLauncher with a WAR?

Comment: I doubt that is possible as it expects a certain format. It certainly won't work when part of another archive (the EAR) . However to me it appears you are doing things you shouldn't be doing in the first place. Why do you need external dependencies added?

Comment: If you want to have skinny wars you should not use spring boot plugin to package your war file so you should use maven-war-pulgin and maven-ear-plugin and configure that in a correct way to get that working. WAR and EAR files have a defined structure where jar/ejb/war/rar etc. have to be located....